# 95% Average Percenttile from IIS Logs

Tags: sql, performance, iis

I'm getting ready for a production push and unfortuanally the previous system does not document performance stats.

I have the IIS logs and have been able to calculate Throughput and average/max requirements.

Is there a way to calculate the 95% time average and max requirements so that the figures don't include the max values? I'm not interested in the full rang of the spectrum, I just want to drop a few of the max times out to see a beter approximation of what the throughput of the current system is.

My Current Query is

```
SELECT
    DatePart(Year,date_time),
    DatePart(Month,date_time),
    DatePart(Day,date_time),
    DatePart(hh,date_time),
    count(*) as [Req/h],
    COUNT(*)/3600 as [Req/s],
    COUNT(*)/60 as [Req/m],
    sum([time-taken]) / count(*) as AverageServerTime,
    Max([time-taken]) as MaxServerTime
  FROM [iis_logs].[dbo].[events]
  where 
  uri_stem like 'stemprefix/%' and 
  host ='www.domain.com'
   and date_time > '11/8/2011'
   and date_time < '11/9/2011'
  group by  
    DatePart(Year,date_time),
    DatePart(Month,date_time),
    DatePart(Day,date_time),
    DatePart(hh,date_time)
```

Comment: 95% of all time or of that hour?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do what I'm looking for (it doesn't report based on hour, but that good enough for my purposes).

```
Select 
    sum(t.time) / count(*) as AverageServerTime,
    Max(t.time) as MaxServerTime
    From
    (
SELECT Top 95 percent
    [time-taken] as time
  FROM [iis_logs].[dbo].[events]
  where 
  uri_stem like 'prefix%' and 
  host ='www.domain.com'
   and date_time > '11/8/2011'
   and date_time < '11/9/2011'
  order by [time-taken]
) t
```